# Trying to create a mediocre cookie clicker in python with tkinter, doesn't print?

Tags: python, tkinter

So i decided to do this for a school project and am completely new to tkinter (but not new to python). But in the parts where the "cookie" values should be printed - they dont get printed.

I dont know how to properly paste code here so here's github:  https://gist.github.com/avaque/a5fd47b896c8ff4e9e52d206994187ce

It looks like a mess, but thats not what matters (i think). The problem is that it doesn't print integers defined as "a" representing the cookie amount.

I started from this code: https://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_buttons.php
...and in that one the string gets printed. Is the value type a problem here?

And also is it possible for the cookie amount to be displayed in a button's text? (look at row 70-74)

Comment: To properly paste code, just copy it in your text editor, paste it in the Stack Overflow edit box, make sure it's selected, and click the `{}` icon in the editor (or hit Ctrl-K).

Comment: Also, make sure to strip down your program to the smallest example that reproduces the problem (and to include example data that triggers it, if relevant). See [mcve] in the help for more details.

Comment: Anyway, without even looking at your code, I'd give at least 50/50 odds that you're running into the most common reason for people having problems with buttons in their first Tkinter app: instead of assigning a function as the `command` callback, you _call_ the function, and assign the _result_. Like `mybutton = tk.Button(parent, text='Whatever', command=myclick())` instead of `mybutton = tk.Button(parent, text='Whatever', command=myclick)`. Does that look right?

Comment: How am i supposed to change the certain integer values without calling the function with extra brackets under command? Like `mybutton = tk.Button(parent, text='Whatever', command=myclick(a,b,c))`

Comment: If you put your code here, I can show you exactly how to fix it. But more generally, there are two answers: you can `from functools import partial` and then write `command=partial(myclick, a, b, c)`, or you can define a new function, either elsewhere with `def` or directly inline with `lambda`, like `command=lambda: myclick(a, b, c)`. Either way, you get a function that takes no arguments, and, when called, calls `myclick` with the values `a, b, c` as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that it doesn't print integers defined as "a" representing the cookie amount.

If I understand correctly, your `buttonzy` is supposed to print the amount when clicked, and it doing just that. The main problem is that you're not updating your `a` variable correctly.

`slogan = tk.Button(frame, text="Cookie click!", command=clicc(a,b))`

First thing: you can't directly send arguments to functions used as commands to your tkinter buttons. One approach is to use a [lambda operator](https://pythonprogramming.net/passing-functions-parameters-tkinter-using-lambda/). So you could rewrite the line above (and all the other ones that try to send arguments to the command functions) as follows:

`slogan = tk.Button(frame, text="Cookie click!", command=lambda: clicc(a,b))`

Just a reminder that if you don't need to send any arguments, there's no need to use lambda.

The second problem you are having is with the `clicc()` function. When you call it from the `slogan` button, you're sending the `a` and `b` variables, and, supposedly updating the value from `a`. What actually happens is that, when you send the values from `a` and `b` to the function, these values are allocated to local variables, that shadow the names from your global variables. So any alteration that you might do inside the function, as `a=a+b`, will only change the value from you local variables, and leave your global variables unaltered. The same happens in the `boostie()` function.
You can read more about the local/global variables dynamics [here](https://pythonspot.com/global-local-variables/).

The most direct solution to you problem, although far from the most elegant, is to add the `global` keyword with the variable names at the start of the functions that do try to modify the values from global variables. For example, your clicc() function could look like:

```
def clicc(x, y):
    global a
    a=x+y
```

Notice how I changed the first argument from `a` to `x`, so as to not use the same variable names.

Another solution would be to work with other types of objects, like lists or even classes, to avoid the need of global variables, so you might want to look into that.

> And also is it possible for the cookie amount to be displayed in a button's text?

In the link you've provided, they show an example with a label, but it is exactly the same with buttons. You can do something like `buttonzy.config(text=str(a))` after updating the value from `a`.